# proof of a definite integral

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

Is there a proof of the definite integral function given below. I found the result by trial and error method and is stumped by the simplicity of the result. It seems to work for all the values for n > 1. I had calculated it through mathematical tools available online. Also, the result comes out to be true as n tends to infinity which can be found by simply using the sandwich theorem result.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Is there a formal proof for this result below?

$$f(n) = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n] {1-x^n}} = \frac{\pi}{n\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes there is a proof using Beta integrals (by setting $x^n=u$) for which I should find a reference soon.

Comment: The stated identity in the second equation is not correct.

Comment: I had tried to evaluate LHS with the values for n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and corresponding values on RHS. I found the results to be identical. I will be happy if you can give me an example where for integral value of n > 1, the LHS and RHS do not match. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the calculations for whichever value of $n$ you want ? A commented by heropup, it does not seem to be correct (at least to me too).

Comment: It does not work for $n=1.7$ Using the TI, the integral gives 1.65335 but the RHS produces 1.9213

Comment: I suppose, after rectifying the question, now it does satisfy for all values of n > 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Modification following the updating of the text:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt[n]{1-x^n}} =\dfrac{1}{n}B\left(\dfrac{1}{n},1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\left(\pi \dfrac{1}{n}\right)}\ \ \ (1)$$

- the first equality will receive a proof below.
- the second equality comes from a property of Beta integral.
- the last equality comes from the complement formula: $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}$ (valid for $0<x<1$)

Proof of the first equality: I have used the following change of variable $x^n=u$ which is equivalent to $x=u^{1/n}$, the differential of which is $dx=(1/n) u^{1/n-1} du$.

Then the integral in (1) becomes $$(1/n) \int_0^1  u^{1/n-1} (1-u)^{-1/n}du$$

Identifying this integral with the definition of the Beta integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_integral :

$$B(a,b)=\int_0^1  u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-1}du$$

we get $(1/n) B(1/n,1-1/n)$.

Comment: Hi Jean, you are right. I missed on putting the nth root in the original question. That is my fault.

Comment: Now I understand. It's the complement formula that's involved... I modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jean. I understood the solution.